# too many values to unpack (expected 2) in array

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
for image_x, image_y in (training_low_imgs, training_high_imgs):
```

The below error is getting in the above line.

> too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Please note that both the shapes of training_low_imgs and training_high_imgs are (10, 256, 256, 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the built-in function `zip`:

```
for image_x, image_y in zip(training_low_imgs, training_high_imgs):
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot about `zip`:

```py
for image_x, image_y in zip(training_low_imgs, training_high_imgs):
```